# Map Azure DevOps project to new folder

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I have a project that uses an Azure DevOps repository for source management. This project is already mapped to a folder on my dev machine.

I'm a bit concerned that my local folder may have gotten corrupted due to my backup software. I want to now bring the code down into a new folder on my dev machine and want to make sure that I follow the correct steps.

Do I follow these steps?

1. First, remove existing mapping between the local repo on my dev machine and the source repo on Azure DevOps
2. Then create a new folder which will be mapped to the source control on Azure
3. Then map the repo on Azure to the new folder

Are these correct steps in making sure that I get the latest committed code into a new folder on my dev machine?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming TFVC based on the terminology you're using.

There's no need to create a new workspace. You can simply ensure that your existing workspace is reset to the server version.

In [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/download-get-files-from-server?view=azure-devops#get-a-specific-version-of-some-files), right click on the root folder, choose "Get Specific Version", and make sure the *Overwrite writable files that are not checked out* and *Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version* boxes are checked.

Or use [`tf get /force`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-command?view=azure-devops). It's the CLI equivalent of what's described above.

Note that this will **remove** any changes that haven't been committed to source control or shelved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. One follow up question, will this process remove any files that were added? More specifically, I made a mistake today and let OneDrive get into my solution folder and the syncing process created a whole bunch of files that end with `-copy`. I guess OneDrive syncing creates duplicates for all files that it handles. I stopped the syncing process as soon as I noticed it but now I have these annoying `-copy` files that I need to remove. Would this reset process remove these files?